# ¿Porque cuando cargo mi pagina realizada con php me aparece un error en linux y en windows si carga correctamente?

Tags: php

Tengo un problema, y no he encontrado la solución. Lo que pasa es que cargo mi proyecto en xamp, htdocs, en windows y me abre la pagina y todo sin ningun inconveniente. Pero al realizar lo mismo en linux me aparece este error en la web.

Warning: require_once(/inicio.php): failed to open stream: No existe el archivo o el directorio in /opt/lampp/htdocs/festivalvallenato/index.php on line 12

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/inicio.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/festivalvallenato/index.php on line 12

En linux tambien utilizo el xamp, y guardo el mismo proyecto de windows en linux pero nose porque me genera el error.

Este es mi index.php, agradezco su ayuda. Gracias.

```
// Pequeña lógica para capturar la pagina que queremos abrir
$pagina = isset($_GET['p']) ? strtolower($_GET['p']) : 'inicio';


// El fragmento de html que contiene la cabecera de nuestra web
require_once 'header.php';


/* Estamos considerando que el parámetro enviando tiene el mismo nombre del archivo a cargar, si este no fuera así
se produciría un error de archivo no encontrado */
require_once '/' . $pagina. '.php';

// Otra opción es validar usando un switch, de esta manera para el valor esperado le indicamos que página cargar


// El fragmento de html que contiene el pie de página de nuestra web
require_once 'footer.php';
```

Comment: Revisa que tu archivo inicio.php este en minúsculas.

Comment: Ya he revisado toda esa parte, pero nada...

Comment: Hola buenos días, verifica que  la ruta sea correcta.  Veo que estas colocando un **/**  después del requiere_once.  Si la página esta al mismo nivel que el header y footer  en  algunos servidores linux, se me ha dado el.caso que no hace falta el **/** .

Answer (score 1):

Tienes el error en:

```
require_once '/' . $pagina. '.php';
```

Si le pones un / al inicio en Linux te refieres a una ruta absoluta, por lo tanto estas diciendo que tu archivo está en /inicio.php.

Puedes borrar el / inicial, o ponerle un punto antes porque ./ se refiere al directorio actual

Estas dos formas te deberían funcionar

```
require_once './' . $pagina. '.php';
require_once $pagina. '.php';`
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo. Me funciono de maravilla. Muchas bendiciones para tu vida.